# What does the position of Jesus indicate in Acts 7:55? Is there a third person next to God in this account?

Tags: acts

Acts 7:55 of the American Standard Version says, But he, being full of the Holy Spirit, looked up stedfastly into heaven, and saw the glory of God, and Jesus standing on the right hand of God. What does Jesus' position indicate? Is there a third person next to God in this account?

Comment: I do not understand the question - why does Acts 7:55 suggest a third person beside God on the throne.  I read only two - the Father and Son.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: Did Jesus become the Almighty God again and sat on the throne after his resurrection, or is it the Almighty God, his Father, sitting on the throne? Ephesians 1:20. If Jesus is on the right hand of His Father, does Jesus position indicate equality with the Father?

Comment: When Jesus rose, He sat at the right hand of the Father in heaven signifying His equality

Comment: 2 Gods? One on the throne, the other on the right? Can you please provide verse or verses supporting your comment.

Comment: One God, two persons here.  See Matt 26:64, Mark 16:19, Luke 22:69, Acts 2:33, 34, 5:31, 7:55, 56, Rom 8:34, Eph 1:20, Col 3:1, Heb 1:3, 8:1, 10:12, etc.

Comment: Nothing there about equality of the Father with the Son. No 2 Gods. There is no Mark 16:19.

Comment: Agreed - no 2 Gods but one.  Both sitting on the same throne equates to equality.  Mark 16:19 says: After the Lord Jesus had spoken to them, He was taken up into heaven and sat down at the right hand of God."

Answer (score 1):

Jesus' place at the "right hand" symbolizes the position and power He has above all others.  In Ephesians 1 19-21 Paul states "And what is the surpassing greatness of His power toward us, the ones believing according to the working of His mighty strength which He worked in Christ in raising Him from the dead, and He seated Him at His right hand in the heavenlies, far above all principality and authority and power and dominion, and every name being named, not only in this world, but also in the coming age" (Ephesians 1:19-21). I don't believe there would be a third person visible in this instance.

Answer (score -1):

@derek made a good point about Jesus *sitting* at God's right hand, which is place of honor and authority. Note, however, that Jesus was *standing*. Apparently, Jesus sufficiently impressed by Stephen to stand up.

I don't see any reason to think that there is third person.